# Left Recursion Elimination, Star Enclosure

Tags: recursion, compiler-construction, left-recursion

I have a grammar that has left recursion I tried removing them and I was able to remove two of them but for one of them I don't know what to do!
Here is the grammar:

```
R -> R "|" S 
R -> S 
S -> S.T 
S -> T 
T -> T* 
T -> U 
U -> (R) 
U -> a 
U -> "ε"
```

I removed the left recursion in rule 1 and 3 but I don't know what to do for rule #5 which is a star enclosure.

I'd be grateful if you help on this problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show how you removed left recursion on 1 and 3? I'm sure you can apply the techniques you used here for `T`.

Comment: Context-free grammars don't have "star enclosures". Perhaps the original grammar was actually `T->T "*"`, in which case the procedure is the same as the other two.